# JavaScript Time Zone Offset does not match Windows Offset

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I am having an unique issue using JavaScript. When running the below code my system which is in timezone `UTC -5 Eastern Standard Time` I am getting the value as `-4 UTC`, it should have been `-5 UTC`.

Currently daylight saving is enabled but JavaScript seems to be unaware about it. What's wrong here, is there any other way to retrieve the correct offset?

```js
var d = new Date();
var tz = d.toString().split("GMT")[1].split(" (")[0];
alert(tz);
```

**Time and timezone from my system:**

[image]

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "running the below code in the timezone UTC -5 Eastern Standard Time"? Please be as specific as you can. Note that Eastern Time at the moment is UTC-4, because it's actually in Eastern Daylight time. (You say that "currently daylight saving is enabled" which would explain it... I'm not at all sure what you mean by "Javascript seems to be agnostic about it".)

Comment: Thanks jon..but my system has it as UTC -05. I have pasted the snapshot from my system in my post. By "Javascript seems to be agnostic about it' I meant Js seems not to be aware of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now *(April 8, 2015)* [EST – Eastern Standard Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/est) (-05:00 UTC) is not in effect, however, [EDT – Eastern Daylight Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/edt) is (-04:00 UTC). The values being returned by the JavaScript Date object are correct.

The line *"(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)"* in the Date and Time Dialog is misleading. That line is not stating the current offset, just the offset for the time zone when DST is not in effect.

Also you can simplify your JavaScript, there is no need to parse the return of `toString()`, in fact it is considered bad practice.

```js
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

document.write("UTC offset in minutes: " + offset 
               + ", offset in hours: " + offset / 60);
```

---

Just some food for thought.

I am not a date and time expert by any means but I generally find it helpful to think of a time zone as something different then a UTC offset.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)

> A time zone is a region that has a uniform standard time for legal, commercial, and social purposes. It is convenient for areas in close commercial or other communication to keep the same time, so time zones tend to follow the boundaries of countries and their subdivisions.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset)

> The UTC offset is the difference in hours and minutes from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) for a particular place and date.

This distinction is important, take the Canadian province of Saskatchewan for example.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Saskatchewan)

> The Canadian province of Saskatchewan is geographically located in the Mountain Time Zone. However, most of the province observes Central Standard Time year-round. As a result, it is effectively on daylight saving time (DST) year round, as clocks are not turned back an hour in autumn.

So here is an example of one time zone (Mountain Time Zone) having multiple UTC offsets at the same time. Or if you prefer Saskatchewan belongs to the Mountain Time Zone from March to November and the Central Time Zone for the rest of the year.

Comment: K..if UTC -5 is not in effect currently. But I change the time to UTC -5 EST in my system properties, shouldnt my code give me -5 instead of -4 because my system clock has UTC -5.

Comment: @Ranjith, I am not running windows so I can't easily reproduce. I will see what I can find though. Also, looking at your screen shot it appears that windows thinks that EDT is set. But yes if you change the system time the change should effect the JS Date object.

Comment: @Ranjith, try unchecking the "*automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time*" checkbox. Reference: http://superuser.com/questions/35544/where-is-the-daylight-saving-time-setting-in-windows-7

Comment: No I cant actually change any settings in the computer as JS runs in clients computer and I cant change it there.

Comment: hmm, so is that screen shot being sent to you as a bug report?

Comment: Thats correct..also when i tried running it in my system changing to UTC -5 I get UTC -4 in JS.

Comment: I assume this is Windows 7? What browser is the issue reproducible in?

Comment: @Ranjith, I am on a windows machine at the moment. I have changed the time zone and turned daylight savings on and off. I am unable to reproduce the issue in either Chrome or IE 10. In addition my testing on Ubuntu 14.04 with Chrome, Firefox and Opera did not reveal an issue either. Based on the available information I can only assume that both you and the user that filled the bug report are confused by the line *"(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)"* in the Date and Time Dialog. That line is not stating the current offset, just the offset for the time zone.

Comment: Exactly.  The offsets listed in the Windows time zone settings are not the *current* offsets, they are just the *standard* offsets, which apply only when DST is not in effect in each zone.

Comment: @MattJohnson, do you think it would be helpful if I added my observation to the answer?

Comment: I also added some information about the display names to [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: You are absolutely right. I understood the issue incorrectly..the issue is with displaying the timezone name(eg: EDT, IST etc). I have posted another question for that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544763/incorrect-timezone-name-in-javascript-only-in-ie