# Incorrect timezone name in javascript only in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, datetime, timezone

I am using the below mentioned code for getting the timezone name/id in the clients timezone. Using the below code I get `EDT` for United state clients but now when I try it in Indian timezone I get it as `UTC` instead of `IST`.

This issue is occurring only for IE all other browsers give me the correct values, how can I get the correct value in IE which is `IST`?

```js
var now = new Date().toString();
var TZ = now.indexOf('(') > -1 ?
now.match(/\([^\)]+\)/)[0].match(/[A-Z]/g).join('') :
now.match(/[A-Z]{3,4}/)[0];
if (TZ == "GMT" && /(GMT\W*\d{4})/.test(now)) 
TZ = RegExp.$1;
document.write(TZ);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toTimeString):

> The `toTimeString()` method is especially useful because compliant
>   engines implementing ECMA-262 may differ in the string obtained from
>   `toString()` for `Date` objects, as the format is
>   implementation-dependent; simple string slicing approaches may not
>   produce consistent results across multiple engines.

I suggest you try using `.toTimeString()`:

```
(new Date()).toTimeString().match(/\(([^\)]+)\)/)[1]
```

I believe that should give you what you want.

Comment: Sorry!!Not working..even this solution displays `UTC` instead of `IST`.

Comment: Is it possible that the computer running IE is simply not properly configured? :)

Comment: When all else fails to make sense, check the settings.

Comment: No..You can too try it..just change your system time zone to +5.30 IST and run the script..you will get UTC always